# Is there a purpose to this _com_ptr_t move assignment?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, swap, move-semantics

So we have this code

```
_com_ptr_t& operator=(_com_ptr_t&& cp) throw()
{
    if (m_pInterface != cp.m_pInterface) {
        Interface* pOldInterface = m_pInterface;

        m_pInterface = cp.m_pInterface;
        cp.m_pInterface = nullptr;

        if (pOldInterface != nullptr) {
            pOldInterface->Release();
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

The `pOldInterface` is `Release()d` on move assignment. Why are move assignment/constructor operations not implemented as swaps which lets the `Release()` occur naturally on moved object's destructor just use the `nullptr` assignment or `Release()` to manually trigger it early?

I always implement move constructors as swap operations. Is this bad practice?

My code would be

```
_com_ptr_t& operator=(_com_ptr_t&& cp) throw()
{
    if (m_pInterface != cp.m_pInterface) {
        Interface* pOldInterface = m_pInterface;
        m_pInterface = cp.m_pInterface;
        cp.m_pInterface = pOldInterface;
        // or just std::swap(m_pInterface, cp.m_pInterface);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Is there a reasoning behind MS `_com_ptr_t` choice? This question also applies to any move assignment/constructor so this context is more/less relevant. It's all about whether we release data or we swap it?

Comment: The C++ COM objects are just thin wrappers around a C API, which doesn't know about C++ rvalues or move semantics.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The COM part is irrelevant. Many devs release on move assign/construct even for non-com objects instead of just swapping resources when they are swappable.

Comment: This in't something that is generic or anything, it's an implementation detail that is up to each library or (non-COM) interface specification. You must always do what the documentation specifies what you need to do.

Comment: Anyway, if the structures doesn't implement move semantics or swapping you need to handle it yourself in your code, the compiler can't create such code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I always implement move constructors as swap operations. Is this bad
>   practice?

Normally note a bad practice, but depends on what `Release()` does (in the first code). If the `Release()` has to take care of any related objects upon `Interface` movements, the implementation might be different than a simple swap operation.

For a trivial case, I personally prefer [`std::exchange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange#Notes) idiom (need [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) or later), which kind of make sense in the move-operations.

```
_com_ptr_t& operator=(_com_ptr_t&& cp) throw()
{
    if (m_pInterface != cp.m_pInterface)
    {
        m_pInterface = std::exchange(cp.m_pInterface, nullptr);
    }
    return *this;
}
```